# Bootstrap carousel slider indicators not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

on my website I have implemented the carousel slider from bootstrap. The problem is that the indicators are sliding the page down instead of changing the slides. Can anyone help? The website is: [www.vornet.net](http://www.vornet.net) (you can look into the source through the browser)

I would be grateful for anyone help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your Web page.  You have written a script in footer at line 641 to 652. This conflicts the functioning of left right arrow so they are not doing the action what they should.